# while clicking on the push notification not going to corresponding activity using pending intent in android

Tags: android, android-intent, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-pendingintent

I am using pending Intent for moving to another activity after getting the push notification through fire base. I tried almost all solutions but when clicking on the notification every time it will redirect to the login screen.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, PendingTicketFragment.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1 /* Request code */, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
         .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo_river)
         .setContentTitle("CEMPIA Message")
         .setContentText("CEMPIA Ticket Escalated to you for"+" "+lp.getUsername())
         .setAutoCancel(true)
         .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.logo_river))
         .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
         .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

assert notificationManager != null;
notificationManager.notify(1 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Comment: Is PendingTicketFragment is Fragment or FragmentActivity?

Comment: We need to provide activity reference to PendingIntent.getActivity() but you are sending fragment

Answer (score 0):

@Shane PendingTicketFragment is a fragment

Token Api.java

```
public class TOKEN_API extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    SingletonePage1Data page1Data = SingletonePage1Data.getSingletonePage1Data();
    SingleToneLoginProperties lp = SingleToneLoginProperties.getSingleToneLoginProperties();
    String targetURL;
    String token;
    private Activity act;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    private final static int NOTIFICATION_ID = 412434;

    public TOKEN_API(String token){
        this.token=token;
    }
    public TOKEN_API(String token, Activity act){
        this.token=token;
        this.act=act;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
//        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(act);
//        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Prepareing .....");
//        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
//        mProgressDialog.setProgress(0);
//        //mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
//        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        //mProgressDialog.show();

    }

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String ret_str = "";
        try {
            Log.e("ERROR","1");
            targetURL = CaLoginActivity.server_ip+"/json/updateToken?userID="+lp.getUserid()+"&tokenID="+token;
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(targetURL);
            final HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 50000);
            HttpClient fbClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
//            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));
            HttpResponse response = fbClient.execute(post);
            InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"));
            Log.e("ERROR","3");
            String line = "";
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                ret_str=ret_str+ line;
            }
            br.close();
            is.close();
            fbClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
            Log.e("ERROR","2      "+targetURL);

            // ============================================================================
        } catch (Exception e) {
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            Log.e("ERROR", e.toString());
//            hand.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }
        return ret_str;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String results) {
        try{
            Log.e("TOKEN_API RETURN DATA", results.toString());

            // creating JSONObject
            JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(results);
            String returnMsg = jo.getString("returnMsg");
            String returnCode = jo.getString("returnCode");
            String tokenID = jo.getString("tokenID");
            String userID = jo.getString("userID");

            Log.e("TOKEN_RES_FROM_SERVER", ""+returnMsg);
            Log.e("TOKENID_RES_FROM_SERVER", ""+tokenID);
            Log.e("TOKEN_UID_FROM_SERVER", ""+userID);

            if(returnMsg.equalsIgnoreCase("success")||
                    returnCode.equalsIgnoreCase("200")){

                Log.e("TOKEN_RESONSE_ERROR", "success");

                Intent intent = new Intent(act, PendingTicketFragment.class);
//                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
//                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
//                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
//                Random randomGenerator = new Random();
//                int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(100);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(act, 1 /* Request code */, intent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

                Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
                NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(act)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo_river)
                        .setContentTitle("CEMPIA Message")
                        .setContentText("CEMPIA Ticket Escalated to you for"+" "+lp.getUsername())
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(act.getResources(), R.drawable.logo_river))
                        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                        .setOngoing(true)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

                NotificationManager notificationManager =
                        (NotificationManager)act.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                assert notificationManager != null;
                notificationManager.notify(1 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
                }
            if(returnMsg.equalsIgnoreCase("Updation failed")||
                    returnCode.equalsIgnoreCase("400")){
                Log.e("TOKEN_RESONSE_ERROR", "Updation failed");
            }
            if(returnMsg.equalsIgnoreCase("exception")||
                    returnCode.equalsIgnoreCase("401")){
                Log.e("TOKEN_RESONSE_ERROR", "exception");
            }
            if(returnMsg.equalsIgnoreCase("Token empty")||
                    returnCode.equalsIgnoreCase("402")){
                Log.e("TOKEN_RESONSE_ERROR", "Token empty");
            }
            if(returnMsg.equalsIgnoreCase("userID empty")||
                    returnCode.equalsIgnoreCase("403")){
                Log.e("TOKEN_RESONSE_ERROR", "userID empty");
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("TOKEN_API ERROR", e.toString());
        }

    }
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

}
```